# What's the difference between different combinations of slashes in base tag href attribute

Tags: html

I've noticed that a browser behaves differently if I mix slashes in the `href` attribute of `base` tag. I know what `base` tag is used for. I'm wondering what's the difference in terms how a browser resolves the path in the following configurations:

```
<base href="http://domain.com/homework">
<base href="http://domain.com/homework/">
<base href="/homework">
<base href="/homework/">
<base href="homework/">
<base href="homework">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just test it:

```js
var base = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('base')),
    a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('a')),
    urls = ["http://domain.com/homework", "http://domain.com/homework/", "/homework", "/homework/", "homework/", "homework"];
a.href = "foo";
for (var url of urls) {
  base.href = url;
  console.log('Using base: ' + url + '\nRelative URL: foo\nAbsolute URL: ' + a.href);
}
```

```css
div.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: thanks, how come `a.href` property is updated when `base.href` is udpated?  it seems that only property updated, not the attribute in DOM

Comment: @Maximus That's because `href` is a getter which returns the absolutized URL.

Answer (score 2):

`http://domain.com/homework`, `/homework`, and `homework` assumes that all links on the page will be query parameters, if it start with a `?`, fragments, if it starts with a `#`, or sub-paths if it is a string. If you add a `/` to the start of a link it would assume that you wanted to start at the root of the URL and would ignore whatever the base tag is set to.

**Example:**

```
<base href='http://domain.com/do-something'>
<a href='?var1=foo&var2=bar'>foobar</a> <!-- http://domain.com/do-something?var1=foo&var2=bar //-->
<a href='#home'>foobar</a> <!-- http://domain.com/do-something#foobar //-->
<a href='homework'>homework</a> <!-- http://domain.com/do-something/homework //-->
<a href='/homework'>homework</a> <!-- http://domain.com/homework //-->
```

---

By not typing out the full URL but having a `/` at the beginning of the href in the base tag you are implying that you want it to be at the root of the URL you are currently on. Basically `/homework` is shorthand for `http://domain.com/homework`.

**Example:**

Assuming you are currently on the page `http://domain.com/some/page.html` and you have a base set as `<base href='/homework/'>` then when you created a link that looks like this `<a href='current'>Current</a>` it would link you to `http://domain.com/homework/current.

But if you left the `/` off of the beginning of the base tag, so that the base tag looked like this `<base href='homework/'>`, then when you clicked on the same link you would be taken to `http://domain.com/some/homework/current`